# Flutter checkbox not working

Tags: flutter

I am building a list of dynamic checkboxes with the code below, for some reason the checkboxes on click will not change. Any ideas why the checkbox does not change when I click on it, it flickers but does not change.

```
new Expanded(
        child: new FutureBuilder(
            future: _getRefDocs(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return new Text('Waiting to start');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return new Text('');
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  } else {
                    //myInitialData = snapshot.data;
                    return new ListView(
                      //key: new GlobalKey(),
                      //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: snapshot.data.map((dynamic key) {
                        bool myvalue = false;
                        if (selectdocs.contains(key['docid'])) {
                          myvalue = true;
                        }
                        return new Container(
                          //height: 150.0,
                          child: new CheckboxListTile(
                            //key: new Key(key['docid'].toString()),
                              title: new Text(key['docname']),
                              value: myvalue,
                              //selected: myvalue,
                              onChanged: (bool value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  myvalue = value;
                                });

                                if (value == true) {
                                  if (!selectdocs.contains(key['docid'])) {
                                    selectdocs.add(key['docid']);
                                    //selectdocs.add(value)
                                  }

                                } else {
                                  if (selectdocs.contains(key['docid'])) {
                                    selectdocs.remove(key['docid']);
                                  }

                                }
                                //print(selectdocs.toString());
                              }
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                  }
              }
            })
      )
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without studying your code too much it seems you are using a future builder so every time you call setState your future builder kicks off the getRefDocs and overwrites your state. I suggest that you override initState() and do getRefDocs there setting the result to some list. Then use that list of docs with a ListBuilder.